Asymptotic behavior in a modular color-cycling problem
I've been working on the following problem I came up with while experimenting with a well known problem:
A hotel has $k$ rooms, numbered 1 to $k$, each with a unique color-changing light. The lights cycle through the colors red, green, and blue in that order. Initially, all lights are set to red.
$k$ guests arrive one by one:

Guest 1 enters every room and advances the light to the next color (red to green).
Guest 2 enters every second room and advances the light twice (red to blue, or green to red).
This pattern continues, with each guest entering rooms corresponding to their number and advancing the light that many times.

However, there's a mischievous cat in the hotel! Every time a guest leaves a room with the light set to green, the cat sneaks in and changes it back to red.
How many blue lights, as a percentage of k, will be lit at the end of this process?
My findings so far
I've implemented a Python script to simulate this process:
def advance_light(current_color, steps):
    return (current_color + steps) % 3

def cat_action(current_color):
    return 0 if current_color == 1 else current_color

def count_lights(k):
    lights = [0] * k
    for guest in range(1, k + 1):
        for room in range(guest - 1, k, guest):
            lights[room] = advance_light(lights[room], guest)
            lights[room] = cat_action(lights[room])
    return sum(1 for light in lights if light == 2)

for k in [100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000]:
    blue_count = count_lights(k)
    percentage = (blue_count / k) * 100
    print(f"{k} lights: {blue_count} blue ({percentage:.6f}%)")

Running this script, I've observed the following pattern:
100 lights: 48 blue (48.000000%)
1000 lights: 459 blue (45.900000%)
10000 lights: 4448 blue (44.480000%)
100000 lights: 43718 blue (43.718000%)
1000000 lights: 431702 blue (43.170200%)
10000000 lights: 4278351 blue (42.783510%)
100000000 lights: 42485137 blue (42.485137%)

To gain more insights, I've also identified which rooms have blue lights for the case of 100 rooms:
[2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 23, 24, 26, 29, 32, 33, 35, 38, 41, 42, 44, 45, 47, 50, 51, 53, 54, 56, 59, 60, 62, 65, 68, 69, 71, 72, 74, 78, 80, 83, 86, 87, 89, 92, 95, 96, 98, 99]

There is an OEIS sequence that appears to be very similar which is A026179, but it is not quite the same (77 is not a blue light).
After that, I've created 2 plots for all the room numbers up to 1,000,000,000. The first one shows the distribution of rooms with blue lights. The resulting plot shows a nearly perfect straight line, which suggests a consistent distribution of blue lights across the rooms.

The second plot I've done shows how the percentage of blue lights changes as $k$ increases. For big values, it appears to decrease very slowly.

I've shared CSV files of the whole data as well as the python code to generate the data and the plots on Hugging Face. Warning: they're very big files.
To give a complete picture, I've also done simulations without the cat interference, and it appears that the percentage of red lights keeps increasing while green and blue lights mostly keep decreasing:
100 rooms:
Total red lights: 66
Total green lights: 14
Total blue lights: 20
1000 rooms:
Total red lights: 736
Total green lights: 74
Total blue lights: 190
10000 rooms:
Total red lights: 7802
Total green lights: 670
Total blue lights: 1528
100000 rooms:
Total red lights: 80730
Total green lights: 6787
Total blue lights: 12483
1000000 rooms:
Total red lights: 825992
Total green lights: 67709
Total blue lights: 106299
10000000 rooms:
Total red lights: 8400034
Total green lights: 662204
Total blue lights: 937762
100000000 rooms:
Total red lights: 85106654
Total green lights: 6405809
Total blue lights: 8487537

My question
Given these observations, particularly the apparent linear relationship in the distribution of blue lights, I'm curious about the asymptotic behavior of this system:

Is it possible to prove the percentage of blue lights converge to a specific value as $k$ approaches infinity? If so, what is this value? Does it continue decrease indefinitely approaching $0%$ for very large values of $k$?
Is there a mathematical explanation for the seemingly linear distribution of blue lights across room numbers?
Can we derive a good approximation for the percentage of blue lights as a function of $k$?

I've tried to approach this problem analytically, but I'm struggling to find a way to express the number of blue lights. Any insights, approaches, or references that could help understand the asymptotic behavior of this problem would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE: I searched for the smallest congruence classes that show properties without overlap and found:
$$always\ red = 1 \bmod 3, 3 \bmod 9, 9 \bmod 27, 27 \bmod 81, 81 \bmod 243, 243 \bmod 729, \{77, 231, 539, 693\} \bmod 770, 729 \bmod 2187$$
$$always\ blue = 2 \bmod 6, 5 \bmod 15, 6 \bmod 18, 15 \bmod 45, 18 \bmod 54, 45 \bmod 135, 54 \bmod 162, \{11,143,209\} \bmod 231, 135 \bmod 405, \{341,407\} \bmod 462, 162 \bmod 486, \{33,429,627\} \bmod 693, 737 \bmod 924, 405 \bmod 1215, \{1023,1199,1221\} \bmod 1386, 486 \bmod 1458, \{99,1287,1881\} \bmod 2079, 2123 \bmod 2310, 2211 \bmod 2772, 3047 \bmod 3234, 1215 \bmod 3645, \{3069,3597,3663\} \bmod 4158, 1458 \bmod 4374, \{17, 323, 527, 629, 731, 1037, 1139, 1241, 1343, 1649, 1751, 1853, 2159, 2363, 2567, 2669, 2771, 3077, 3281, 3383, 3587, 3791, 3893, 4097, 4607\} \bmod 4641, 5819 \bmod 6006, \{297, 3861, 5643\}\bmod 6237, 6369 \bmod 6930, 7667 \bmod 7854, 6633 \bmod 8316, 8591 \bmod 8778, \{4709, 4811, 4913, 5219, 5321, 5627, 5729, 5933, 6137, 6239, 6341, 6443, 6647, 6749, 6953, 7157, 7361, 7463, 7769, 7871, 8279, 8381, 8483, 8891, 8993, 9197\}\bmod 9282$$
All of this should be proved rigorously, but it holds for $10^8$ rooms.
All of this would give a lower bound of the natural density of blue lights of $\frac{7667142635}{19799007228} \approx 38.72488\%$, as well as an upperbound of $\frac{1250063}{2525985} \approx 49.488\%$.
While blue light patterns appear to be quite chaotic, red lights show a nice pattern, that if holds, lets us slightly improve the upperbound:
$$1 - (\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{81} + \frac{1}{243} + \frac{1}{729} + \frac{4}{770} + \frac{1}{2187} + \frac{1}{6561} + \dots) \approx 1 - (\frac{4}{770}+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^i})=1-(\frac{4}{770}+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{381}{770} \approx 49.4805\%$$

I don't understand how to deal with the cat so please permit me to ignore it. Without the cat, the color of room $n$'s light at the end of the process is $\sigma(n) \bmod 3$ where $\sigma$ is the divisor function
$$\sigma(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} d$$
and we identify $\text{red} = 0, \text{blue} = 1, \text{green} = 2$. The divisor function has the following explicit form based on the prime factorization $n = \prod p^{\nu_p(n)}$ of $n$:
$$\sigma(n) = \prod_p \left( p^{\nu_p(n)} + p^{\nu_p(n) - 1} + \dots + 1 \right).$$
So we can understand why it tends to be divisible by $3$: it's because it suffices for at least one of these factors to be divisible by $3$. It's not hard to see that if $p \equiv 2 \bmod 3$ (which happens half the time by Dirichlet's theorem) then the corresponding factor of $\sigma(n)$ is divisible by $3$ iff $\nu_p(n)$ is odd, and if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ then the corresponding factor of $\sigma(n)$ is divisible by $3$ iff $\nu_p(n)$ is $2 \bmod 3$. $p = 3$ is a special case, and the corresponding factor is never divisible by $3$.
Now we want to understand how likely it is that at least one of these things happens. Here is a heuristic calculation: roughly speaking, these events are independent, and they have "probabilities" (really natural densities)
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \mathbb{P}(\nu_p(n) \equiv 1 \bmod 2) &=& \lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{(p^{i-1} - p^{i-2}) + (p^{i-3} - p^{i-4}) + \dots }{p^i} \\
 &=& \left( \frac{1}{p} \right) \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p}} \\
 &=& \frac{1}{p + 1} \end{eqnarray*}$$
and
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \mathbb{P}(\nu_p(n) \equiv 2 \bmod 3) &=& \lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{(p^{i-2} - p^{i-3}) + (p^{i-5} - p^{i-6}) + \dots}{p^i} \\
 &=& \left( \frac{1}{p^2} - \frac{1}{p^3} \right) \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p^3}} \\
 &=& \frac{1}{p^2 + p + 1}. \end{eqnarray*}$$
So heuristically we expect the "probability" that a natural number $1 \le n \le N$ to have the property that $\sigma(n) \equiv 0 \bmod 3$ (which corresponds to a red light) to be $1$ minus the probability that none of the above events occurs, or
$$\mathbb{P}(\sigma(n) \equiv 0 \bmod 3) \approx \boxed{ 1 - \left( \prod_{p \le N, p \equiv 2 \bmod 3} 1 - \frac{1}{p + 1} \right) \left( \prod_{p \le N, p \equiv 1 \bmod 3} 1 - \frac{1}{p^2 + p + 1} \right) }.$$
This approaches $1$ as $N \to \infty$ but slowly, which matches your simulations. We can get a lower bound by computing this product over the primes $\le N$ for any $N$; for example, computing this product over the first $5$ primes (excluding $3$) gives
$$1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2+1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{5 + 1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{7^2 + 7 + 1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{11 + 1} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{13^2 + 13 + 1} \right) = 0.502 \dots $$
which is at least in the same ballpark as your count of $66$ red lights for the first $100$ rooms (we could get closer with a few more primes). This could all be made rigorous with error bounds and so forth using techniques from analytic number theory.

Now let me describe what I find difficult about the cat. Adding the cat in corresponds to a variant of computing $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} d \bmod 3$ where we add the divisors up in order (so the exact order matters) and, whenever the result is $1 \bmod 3$, we round it down to $0 \bmod 3$. This is equivalent to subtracting ($\bmod 3$) the number of times that the partial sum $\sum_{d \mid n, d \le i} d$ is $1 \bmod 3$, which seems quite tricky to analyze precisely. OTOH the connection to A026179 suggests there actually might be a pretty nice pattern here, so who knows.

Thinking of the cat interference as a rounding error makes me think that it is likely statistically insignificant for very big numbers, which would suggest that the asymptotic behavior is the same, so the "probability" of selecting a red light would also likely approach $1$ as $N \to \infty$, but much more slowly; it is only a conjecture though

@Aldo: well, unfortunately it's very significant, because we're working $\bmod 3$! Even a single intervention by the cat is significant. Actually without your data I would have guessed that the intervention of the cat would scramble everything and make all the colors about equally likely.

A little update you may (or may not) find interesting: for the cat version of the problem, I discovered that all numbers $n \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $n \equiv 4 \bmod 6$ are guaranteed to be red lights; all the numbers $n \equiv 2 \bmod 6$ and $n \equiv 5 \bmod 15$ are blue lights. To put it more simply, ${1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28} \bmod 30$ is always red, and ${2, 5, 8, 14, 20, 26} \bmod 30$ is always blue. This implies the natural density of blue lights is at very least bounded between $\frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$.

With computer assistance I'm able to bound the natural density between $\frac{182}{729}$ and $\frac{365}{364}$. Basically between 25% and 50%.

The second fraction was supposed to be $\frac{365}{729}$.

With further search I found a lower bound of $\frac{14762}{59049} \approx 24.9996$ % and an upperbound of $\frac{29525}{59049} \approx 50.0008$ %. Again, essentially 25% and 50% respectively. I'm afraid this can't be improved any further with the system I found, as I've checked all the primes up to 104729 and the only numbers that appear to form patterns are the congruence classes of $n \bmod 2*3^m$, which appear to only get the lower and upper bounds closer and closer to 25% and 50%.

More extensive (but not really rigorous) search found a lot more properties that hold up to $10^8$, and drastically improved the bounds so they're now 38.4% and 49.488% respectively. I've updated the main post showing the properties that were found. However, the patterns that hold for blue lights seem pretty much random.
